# Pattern for cyclic calls of async operations

Tags: c#, event-handling, task

I want to do some I/O based async operations periodically.
It should not run as fast as possible but with a configurable delay between the cycles.

So far I came up with two different approaches and I am wondering which one is better in regards of ressource consumption.

**Approach 1 with Task.Run()**

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            {
                var handler = new CommunicationService();
                handler.Start();
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class CommunicationService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

        public void Start()
        {
            Run();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(someUri);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configurableValue));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
                    Run();
                }

                Run();
            });
        }
    }
```

So the `async` operation is wrapped in a `Task.Run()` in a `fire and forget` style, so it can be started without blocking.

**Approach 2 with EventHandler**

```
 internal class CommunicationService
    {
        private event EventHandler CommunicationHandler;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

        public void Start()
        {
            CommunicationHandler = (o, events) => Communicate();
            OnCommunicationTriggered();
        }

        private async void Communicate()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(someUri);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configurableValue));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
                OnCommunicationTriggered();
            }
            OnCommunicationTriggered();
        }

        private void OnCommunicationTriggered()
        {
            CommunicationHandler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

With this approach wrapping in `Task.Run()` is not necessary but is it therefore better?

I created a .Net console application for both approaches and recorded following performance counters over a few minutes and did not see that much difference to be honest:

1. \Process(Events)% Processor Time (approach 2 ~20 % higher)
2. \Process(Events)\Private Bytes (almost equal, approach 2 slighlty
   lower)
3. \Process(Events)\Thread Count (approach 2 ~ 25% lower)
4. .NET CLR LocksAndThreads(Events)# of current logical Threads
   (almost equal, approach 2 slighlty higher)
5. .NET CLR LocksAndThreads(Events)# of current physical Threads
   (almost equal, approach 2 slighlty higher)
6. .NET CLR LocksAndThreads(Events)\Contention Rate / sec (approach 2
   ~ 50% higher)

Am I missing the point here with these counters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are really doing the same thing. The event option seem to add a unneeded layer of complexity. There is not significant difference in resource consumption.

A more appropriate option would be to use a [timer.timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-3.1) or [threading.timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netcore-3.1). This makes the code easier to read and understand since it expresses *intent*. Behind the scene all of the alternatives result in more or less the same thing.

You will need to consider how you count the time. Should the execution time be included in the timing interval or not? Often the interval is much longer than the execution time, so it does not matter. If it does matter you might need to set the timer to only trigger once, and [reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.change?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Timer_Change_System_TimeSpan_System_TimeSpan_) the timer once your operation has completed.

Comment: only thing is: If the event handler takes longer than the interval time is, than I don't want to "queue up" my event handlers but simply trigger next execution immediately. It should be granted that there is only on handler processing at a time

Comment: @yBother then use a threading.Timer and call `.Change` with a infinite period each time the task completes. Another alternative is a simple loop that starts your work and calls `task.Delay`, that is still more readable than having a pseudo-recursing task.

Comment: I cannot find a way to make threading.timer only trigger once?

Comment: @yBother Read the documentation of `.Change` "**Period** ... Specify System.Threading.InfiniteTimeSpan to disable periodic signaling" I.e. -1.

Answer (score 0):

according to the accepted answer here is my new approach:

```
 internal class EventHandlerService
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private TimeSpan refreshTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        public void Start()
        {           
            _timer = new Timer(Communicate, null, 0,(int)refreshTime.TotalMilliseconds);
        }

        private void Communicate(object stateInfo)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                _timer.Change(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan); // stop the timer
                Console.WriteLine($"Starting at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")}");
                var stopWatch=new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Finishing at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")} after: {stopWatch.Elapsed}");
                    var dueTime = refreshTime.Subtract(stopWatch.Elapsed);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Calced dueTime to: {dueTime.TotalSeconds} at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")}");

                    _timer.Change(Math.Max((int) dueTime.TotalMilliseconds, 0), (int)refreshTime.TotalMilliseconds); // start the timer
                }
            });
        }

      
    }
```

with this approach I got my needs covered:
the actual refresh/timer period does never fall below 5 seconds but if the handler takes longer than 5 seconds, the next execution is being triggered without delay.